# passing object from view to .net controller using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm sending a list of complex objects from controller to the view.
In the view I retrieved that list and converted it to javascript object

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

//javascript code here...
```

I want to send the selected object from that view to the controller.
so I tried this code

> This is javascript code (View)

```
for (i = 0; i < model.length; i++) {
      
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(model[i].VehicleCurrentPosition.Latitude, 
      model[i].VehicleCurrentPosition.Longitude),
      map: map,
          icon: model[i].Vehicle.MarkerPicture
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
          return function () {
              infowindow.setContent(<button onclick="postData(\'' + model[i] + '\')">POST</button>);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
          }
      })(marker, i));
}
```

> Ajax function

```
function postData(model) {
    var f = {};
        f.type = "POST";
        f.url = '@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")';
        f.contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        f.data = JSON.stringify(model);
        f.dataType = "json";
        f.success = function (response) {
            alert("success");
        };
        f.error = function (response) {
            alert("failed");
        };
        $.ajax(f);
};
```

And finally this is my action method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(string model)
{
    //code here...
    return Json("OK");
}
```

The ajax is calling the contoller action successfully but the value passed is null !!
Any suggestions ?

Comment: Have you tried sending the data as object? Not sure if this could help: `JSON.stringify({ model });` Did you check that the client actually sent anything via e.g. the network panel?

Comment: @H.B. Yes I tried! But always getting a null value!
Note that when I tried to send a simple object, example: JSON.stringify({ ID: 123, Name: "John" }); it worked !

Comment: @AlpArselan try to put this string inside object too. and if you use .netcore you could add[fromBody].